# Why does Electrum never complete synchronization with a server?

Tags: wallet, electrum, network, synchronization, server

How do I diagnose why `electrum` never finishes synchronizing?

[image: network]

I've tried selecting networks individually without success.

Can I ping a server to confirm [connectivity](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/how-to-switch-to-a-different-electrum-server/)?

Comment: Electrum 2.6.4 is over 5 years old. Have you tried with a more recent release?

Comment: huh, I was just going with snap:  https://snapcraft.io/electrum   thinking that would be up to date.  thanks @PieterWuille